# iOS 4.1 SDK - Duplicate Symbols in Multiple Static library Linking for Device Builds

Tags: xcode, ios4, linker, ios, xcodebuild

My company is building an app with SDK 4.1 for the iPhone.

To do this we have 3 levels of project dependencies, our main App "CSM" is linking to our SDK called "csm-sdk" (in libsrc_csmsdk.a) csm-sdk then links to our XMLRPC library ("libXMLRPC.a").

When compiling csm-sdk for the device, it include definitions for all of the ObjC classes, and C Functions for oue XMLRPC Library twice.

Then when CSM links, it reports Duplicate objects in the same library file.

We link at all levels with -all_load and -ObjC.

I have another project doing something similar on SDK 3.2, and everything works fine... And this project on 4.1 as a Simulator build everything works fine, only Device fails. Has anyone run in to something similar?

More details below.

Thanks!

Glenn R. Martin

Build Error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMLParser in /Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/csm-sdk/build/Release-iphoneos/libsrc_csmsdk.a(XMLParser.o) and /Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/csm-sdk/build/Release-iphoneos/libsrc_csmsdk.a(XMLParser.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
ProcessProductPackaging "/Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/6EB9AEE7-A844-4017-B076-06C3240F869B.mobileprovision" "build/Release-iphoneos/CSM.app/embedded.mobileprovision"
    cd /Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> "/Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/6EB9AEE7-A844-4017-B076-06C3240F869B.mobileprovision" -o "/Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/build/Release-iphoneos/CSM.app/embedded.mobileprovision"

ProcessProductPackaging dist.plist "build/CSM.build/Release-iphoneos/CSM.build/CSM.xcent"
    cd /Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> /Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/dist.plist -entitlements -format xml -o "/Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/build/CSM.build/Release-iphoneos/CSM.build/CSM.xcent"

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CSM:
   Ld "/Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/build/CSM.build/Release-iphoneos/CSM.build/Objects-normal/armv6/CSM" normal armv6
   Ld "/Users/builder/cc/workingdirs/iphoneclient/build/CSM.build/Release-iphoneos/CSM.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CSM" normal armv7
(2 failures)

Release BUILD failed
```

---

otool dump of Device:

```
Archive : csm-sdk/build/Release-iphoneos/libsrc_csmsdk.a (architecture armv7)
Table of contents from: csm-sdk/build/Release-iphoneos/libsrc_csmsdk.a(__.SYMDEF) (for architecture armv7)
size of ranlib structures: 1960 (number 245)
size of strings: 6256

object           symbol name
XMLParser.o   _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLParser
XMLParser.o   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMLParser
XMLParser.o   .objc_class_name_XMLParser
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._asynchronousData
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._methodName
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._asynchronousConnection
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._asynchronous
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._asyncRequestInProgress
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._queueRequests
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._requestTimeout
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._serviceUrl
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._cachingPolicy
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMLRPC
XMLRPC.o      .objc_class_name_XMLRPC
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLRPC

... Clipped for Brevity ...

CSMWebservice.o l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_NSObject
CSMWebservice.o l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_XMLRPCDelegate
XMLParser.o   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMLParser
XMLParser.o   .objc_class_name_XMLParser
XMLParser.o   _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLParser
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._methodName
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._asynchronousConnection
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._delegate
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._serviceUrl
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._queueRequests
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._requestTimeout
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_IVAR_$_XMLRPC._asynchronousError
XMLRPC.o      .objc_class_name_XMLRPC
XMLRPC.o      _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLRPC
```

otool dump of Simulator:

```
Archive : csm-sdk/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libsrc_csmsdk.a
Table of contents from: csm-sdk/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libsrc_csmsdk.a(__.SYMDEF)
size of ranlib structures: 1520 (number 190)
size of strings: 5080

object           symbol name
CSMWebservice.o _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CSMWebservice
CSMWebservice.o _OBJC_CLASS_$_CSMWebservice
CSMWebservice.o l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_NSObject
XMLParser.o   _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLParser
XMLParser.o   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMLParser
XMLParser.o   .objc_class_name_XMLParser
... No duplication, clipped for brevity ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug in 4.1, in fact when i listed it on rdar it was then listed as a duplicate. I am informed that it has recently been fixed, just hope the fix comes out in the next version.

Comment: What's the status of this bug? I'm still seeing it in Xcode 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should link everything in your final app deployment target and not the individual subtargets.

Comment: Different projects use these. Thus they need those dependents as well... the CSM-SDK requires the XMLRPC library. The CSM-SDK will be used in other projects, and the XMLRPC library is maintained as a separate project, if Xcode cannot handle this functionality it shouldnt have it, and besides, 3.2 SDK did it fine.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone knew of a bug in 4.1 (iOS SDK), or a solution for this project, we are doing it in others fine, but that was for the 3.2 iOS SDK.